# structure member name - search

Tags: c++, structure

In the previous question, i made a big mess there. So i want to give it a new try.

```
struct emp
{
    int salary;
    string empid;
};
struct payroll
{
    int empid;
    int deductions;
};
    emp a1,a2, a3;  

    a1.salary = 9000;
    a1.empid = 1;

    a2.salary = 1000;
    a2.empid = 2;

    a3.salary = 9000;
    a3.empid = 3;

    payroll p1,p1,p3;   

    p1.empid = 1;
    p1.deductions = 10;

    p12.empid = 2;
    p2.deductions = 20;

    p3.empid = 3;
    p3.deductions = 30;
```

now, from the command prompt i have given like this

```
empid = 1;
```

then i need the answer that a1 and p1.
Here i need to check whether structures have the member name : empid - if true - then check for empid = 1.

How to do this in a generic way. I mean if i have 30 structures like this how to do. Give me any idea, if this is not possible, then how to do it using any other data structure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way to dynamically inspect the member variable name of a structure. If you don't want to inspect the member variable name, use an `std::vector` to store the structure instances. Use `std::find_if` to search for a particular instance that satisfies a predicate. See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) for usage example of `find_if`. If you really want to check if a field named `empid` exist in the `struct`, use an `std::map` instead:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> emp;
typedef std::map<std::string, int> payroll;
typedef std::vector<emp> emp_list;
typedef std::vector<payroll> payroll_list;

emp_list emps;
emp a1;
a1["empid"] = 1;
a1["salary"] = 9000;
emps.push_back(a1);
// ...

payroll_list pays;
payroll p1;
p1["empid"] = 1;
p1["deductions"] = 10;
pays.push_back(p1);
// ...

// use an iterator over emps and pays to check for specific items
emp_list::const_iterator eit = emps.begin ();
emp_list::const_iterator eend = emps.end ();
while (eit != eend)
  {
    emp e = *eit;
    int eid = e["empid"];
    if (eid == empid)
      {
        std::cout << e["salary"] << '\n';
      }
    eit++;
  }
// ...
```

Comment: ohh.. yesterday also you gave me the answer. Yes i created vector for structure instances. But find_if gives me the first instance only, and one more thing => if input is : salary=9000, then it should give me a1, a3(first check for member name, next if member name is there - then value). Can you write a sample code for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use a consistent data type for `empid` across all `struct`s.
2. As @Vijay Mathew [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986275/structure-member-name-search/3986288#3986288), use a `vector` and then search. Alternatively you can use a [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) with `empid` as the key, this will give better performance for large numbers of entries.

Comment: this empid is just for the testing purpose, and datatype may not be equal, if have 20 structures with 20 columns - how to use map??? There is no primary key like that. If i search for : deductions = 30 (from command prompt : no other information), then how to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, if you have 30 structures (tables) in your "database", you want to find all structures that have "empid" as a column (i.e. member of structure)? In C++ I'm not aware of a mechanism to test whether a structure has a particular member by name, at least not a name provided at runtime. You need to store this in some form of "meta data" - e.g. maps with string keys that lists a set of structures for example (or encoded in logic with string comparisons etc.)...

Here is a rough sketch...

A "table" class typed on the row type (i.e. structure)

```
class table
{
  // some virtual methods common to all classes..
};

template <typename _Row>
class data_table : public table
{
  // methods

  // real data
  std::vector<_Row> data;
};
```

then you need a database class to hold all the tables..

```
class database
{
  // methods
  std::map<int, boost::shared_ptr<table> > tables; // here int is for a unique id for table
};
```

Now you have a collection of tables, where each table is a set of rows (structures). You then need to define some metadata for the database, i.e. map columns to tables etc..

```
std::multimap<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<table> > columns;
```

This you have to populate using your knowledge of the structures, for example, this map may contain, for your code above:

```
columns["empid"] = id of table<emp>;
columns["empid"] = id of table<payroll>;
```

etc.

Now, you can pass a "query" to your "database" class, where you say something like, "empid" = 1, and then you lookup in the columns map and find all instances of tables, and then each table you can query with "empid" = 1. As to how to map "empid" to the real `empid` field in the structure `emp`, you have to embed that logic into methods in the `emp` structure which `table<emp>` can delegate to (or if you can think of a smart way of storing references to members... )

It's only a suggestion...

Or alternatively, consider using one of the many databases out there which will support real queries, and run either as standalone or embedded!

Edit:

```
struct emp
{
  int empid;
  string empname;

  template <typename T>
  bool matches(const string& field_name, const T& value)
  {
    if (field_name == "empid")
      return empid == value;
    else if (field_name == "empname")
      return empname == value;
    // etc
    return false;
  }

};
```

So the "metadata" is encoded in the logic for test, you pass in a string field name, and then depending on what it is, you compare the appropriate value... This isn't very efficient, but it works...

Comment: yes... it solves the problem of generosity, but i really struck here "As to how to map "empid" to the real empid field in the structure emp", if i give input like this " emp, empid = 1" then how to map empid to emp.empid.  thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also, if you need to parse "emp, empid=1", that is a different problem, I'm hoping you've worked out how to do that?? If not, look at string operations on any of the references out there (such as cplusplus.com)